# Wrong file extension and file name after creating image file with Android's MediaStore (ContentResolver/scoped storage)

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, mediastore, scoped-storage

I am using the [MediaStore and ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item) API to save image files (jpg/png/gif) using `MediaStore.Images`.
It works, but the problem is that all the files are saved with the .jpg extension and the file name is always *"the current time in millis.jpg"*.

Here is an example of what I put in the ContentValues:

```
date_added=1575480356 _display_name=2067623.gif date_modified=1575480356 mime_type=image/gif
```

But after inserting it to the ContentResolver and writing the file, the display name changes to `2067623.jpg` and the file name to `1575480356.jpg`.

**How do I get it to keep the file name and extension**?

Code:

```
    ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
    Uri mediaCollection;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        mediaCollection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
    } else {
        mediaCollection = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

    ContentValues mediaDetails = new ContentValues();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        final String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "my_folder";
        mediaDetails.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        mediaDetails.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);
        mediaDetails.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);
    }
    String mimeType = "image" + "/" + getExtension(p); // jpg/png/gif
    mediaDetails.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
    mediaDetails.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
    mediaDetails.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    mediaDetails.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);

    Uri contentUri = resolver.insert(mediaCollection, mediaDetails);

    write(contentUri, resolver, p, fileName); // Write the file content using resolver.openOutputStream(contentUri)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        mediaDetails.clear();
        mediaDetails.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
        resolver.update(contentUri, mediaDetails, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: You will need 2 different ways of saving the file, depending on the SDK of the phone you are running on. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141440/1797806

Answer (score -2):

Did you find a soution? I did not, so I end up doing this:

```
private void addImageToGalleryLegacy(@NonNull final String imagePath, @NonNull final String fileName) throws IOException {
    File fIn = new File(imagePath);
    String outPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File fOut = new File(outPath, fileName);
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fIn);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fOut);
    copy(in, out);
}
```

Basically (as we are in pre Q) we can copy the image straight to the gallery.
"imagePath" is "Android/data/[package name]/files/Pictures" in my case.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory where you grant access to a specific folder once and then you can write to it at any time. It was much easier and file endings are preserved :)

Comment: @hej2010 Thanks, I will give it a try :)