# Wrong image name and type when saving bitmap Android 8

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

I have a fun that saves bitmap as PNG or JPG (both not working), but seems like using content values not working as expected.

1. File name is incorrect.
2. File type is incorrect.

What am I missing ?
Works on Android 10, but not working on Android 8

```kotlin
fun Bitmap.save(context: Context) {
    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver

    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "test.png")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "test")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)
        }
    }

    val contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val uri = contentResolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues)
    if (uri != null) {
        try {
            contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w", null)?.use {
                if (it.fileDescriptor != null) {
                    with(FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor)) {
                        compress(
                            Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
                            DEFAULT_IMAGE_QUALITY,
                            this
                        )
                        flush()
                        close()
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            contentValues.clear()
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 0)
            contentResolver.update(uri, contentValues, null, null)
        }

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(uri.toString()), null, null)
    }
    recycle()
}
```

Actual file name is **1592205828045** (some timestamp)

Actual file type is **jpg** with **0B** - as it was not saved properly ?

Comment: What is the current file name and file type it's saving ?

Comment: u have it in actual section -> 1592205828045 JPG 0B

Comment: So that is name of the file you are getting currently ... Is it so ?

Comment: yes exactly it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the file, but you still need to write your `Bitmap` to it:

```
fun Bitmap.save(context: Context) {

    ...

    val bitmap = this
    val maxImageQuality = 100

    val uri = contentResolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues)
    if (uri != null) {
        try {
            contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w", null)?.use {
                if (it.fileDescriptor != null) {
                    with(FileOutputStream(it.fileDescriptor)) {
                        bitmap.compress(
                            Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
                            maxImageQuality, this
                        )
                        flush()
                        close()
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        // release pending status of the file
        contentValues.clear()
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
        contentResolver.update(uri, contentValues, null, null)

        // notify media scanner there's a new picture
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(uri.toString()), null, null)
    }
    // don't forget to recycle the bitmap when you don't need it any longer
    bitmap.recycle()
}
```

Comment: if I clear values before update I will get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty values`

Comment: After clearing _contentValues_ we  put in the _MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING_ property again, so it should not be empty.

Comment: IS_PENDING is for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, for SDK below wont work

Comment: and still saved as JPG with timestamp in the name and 0B file size :(

Comment: see the edit, I applied ur solution and still same effect

Comment: works on emulator tho -> Android 10, but not working on Android 8

Answer (score 6):

You will have to maintain 2 different ways of saving images to shared storage. This [post](https://medium.com/@alessandromautone/public-file-storage-on-android-10-622c49a874a9) covers it quite well. Using Media Store API in older phones results in the problem you have described. Some code sample for you (tested in Android 8, 10, and 11).

Add these to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!--  File save functions handles this  -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Add a permission check to your app (code not provided)

When you are ready with your bitmap call either of these functions (depending on the SDK version of the phone that the app is currently running on)

```
    //TODO - bitmap needs null check
      val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmapFile.canonicalPath)

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
         {
           saveBitmapPreQ(bitmap)
         } else {
           saveBitmapPostQ(bitmap)
         }
```

Finally these are the implementations of *saveBitmapPreQ* and *saveBitmapPostQ*

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION") // Check is preformed on function call
private fun saveBitmapPreQ(thisBitmap: Bitmap){
    Log.d("HOME_4", "in pre Q")
    val pictureDirectory = 
   File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), 
   "MyFolder")

    if (!pictureDirectory.exists()){
        pictureDirectory.mkdir()
    }

    val dateTimeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Date())
    val name = "Image_$dateTimeStamp"

    val bitmapFile = File(pictureDirectory, "$name.png")

    try {
        val fileOutputStream = bitmapFile.outputStream()
        thisBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream)
        fileOutputStream.flush()
        fileOutputStream.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("HOME_5", "Pre Q error $e")
    }
```

}

```
private fun saveBitmapPostQ(thisBitmap: Bitmap){
    Log.d("HOME_6", "in post Q")
    val dateTimeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Date())
    val name = "Image_$dateTimeStamp"
    val relativePath = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "MyFolder"


    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)

        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, name)
        put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativePath)
    }

    val contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
    var uri: Uri? = null

    try {
        uri = contentResolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues)

        if (uri == null){
            throw IOException("Failed to create new MediaStore record.")
        }

        outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)

        if (outputStream == null){
            throw IOException("Failed to get output stream.")
        }

        if (!thisBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream)){
            throw IOException("Failed to save bitmap.")
        }
    } catch (e: IOException){
        if (uri != null)
        {
            contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null)
        }

        throw IOException(e)
    }

    finally {
        outputStream?.close()
    }
}
```

I have left log messages in there to help you understand the flow. In the *saveBitmapPostQ* funtions I have taken a few shortcuts. Please read this [post](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10217168-preparing-for-scoped-storage) under the headding **Creating a New File** on how you can improve that function further.